# Mi pagina html no ejecuta sripts

Tags: javascript, html5

Esta es la estructura de mi pagina HTML pero no ejecuta los scripts, que puede ser? Disculpen si se ve desorganizado. Probé en otro HTML que tengo como pruebas y el script funciona normalmente, no se que pudo haber pasado en el HTML principal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <BODY LANG="en-US" BGCOLOR="#000000" DIR="LTR">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Titulo de la pagina</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head> 
<body>
  <div id="container">
    
    <header><h1 ALIGN=CENTER><FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Header</FONT></h1>
    
    </header>
    <center><a href="lab.html"><img src="inicio.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='inicio.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='inicio.jpg"/></a></center>
<hr color="#0080FF">
 <FONT COLOR="#ff0000">¿Qué es?</FONT></font></h2>
    <p><font color = "#2E7429">texto1</font></p>
    <p><font color = "#2E7429">texto2</font></p> <h2><font color="FEFEFE"></font></h2>

        <h2><FONT COLOR="#ff0000">header2</font></h2>
        <p><font color = "#2E7429">texto3</font></p>
        <h2><FONT COLOR="#ff0000">header3</font></h2>
        <p><font color = "#2E7429">texto4</font></p> 
        <h2><FONT COLOR="##2E7429">header4)</font></h2> 
        <br><br>
         <font size="6"><FONT COLOR="#ff0000"><p><marquee>texto5</marquee></FONT>
    </div>         
</body>
</html>
<script src="screen.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Este es el Javascript:

```js
var images = [
  'Space.gif',  'Windows.gif'
]
setInterval(function() {
  const image = images.shift()
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`
  images.push(image)
}, 3000);
```

EDIT 2: El Visual Studio Code me muestra el siguiente error: "Unterminated string literal." y viene de aquí:

```
<center><a href="lab.html"><img src="inicio.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='inicio.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='inicio.jpg"/></a></center>
```

Ese pedazo de codigo como se puede ver son los botones de la pagina. Será que esa es la causa que no corra el script asi no tenga nada que ver con los botones de la pagina? Como puedo corregir esto?

Saludos!

Comment: Checa si tu navegador tiene habilitado Javascript y si ese no es el problema, sería necesario que compartas tu archivo JS también

Comment: Hola si, el navegador tiene JS habilitado, de hecho es el mismo que uso con mi HTML de pruebas, con ese HTML funciona perfectamente. Saludos!

Comment: No sé si sea la causa pero, la estructura de tu HTML está extremadamente mal estructurado. Hay una etiqueta body abierto pero no cerrado: error. El atributo lang="" debe ir dentro de la etiqueta HTML. La etiqueta script debe ir dentro y al final de body. Algunas etiquetas se abren con mayúscula y cierra con minuscula: error. Arregla todo eso y luego quita el atributo onmouseover de tu etiqueta a, solo para probar el error

Comment: Si es la imagen del boton que no te cambia es porque te falta la comilla de cierre ', tiene que quedarte asi onmouseout="this.src='inicio.jpg'"

Comment: Solucionado! Lo que pasaba era que tenia programado que la imagen del fondo de la pagina cambiara cada cierto tiempo pero esto no pasaba en este html en especifico pero en otros si, y despues de tanto buscar era que habia puesto exactamente la misma imagen pero con diferente nombre en el script :/ Ahora si funciona de maravilla! PD: Yo también se que es horroroso leer mis HTML, uno de mis grandes problemas en la programacion es la identación :( de todas formas muchas gracias por sus observaciones!

Comment: Y yo que acabo de estructurar todo correctamente y funcionando perfectamente

Comment: Es imposible cometer errores en la estructura con un editor como Visual Studio. Ya que hace su cierre automático, y muestra los errores. Es al raro tu caso

Comment: @ Narciso Aifuz Uy si todavia tienes mi HTML estructurado correctamente publicalo porfa, todavía me faltan muchas paginas por realizar! Estaré muy agradecido! Lo que pasa es que es mi primera clase de programación o bien de diseño web, y apenas estoy empezando a aprender sobre todo esto.  Mil gracias por tu respuesta por cierto!

Comment: Ok. Tengo en el móvil. Allá voy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Éste es una copia de tu código con lijero arreglo de apertura y cierre de etiqueta, corrección de mayúscula a minúscula, eliminación de etiqueta extra, y completado comillas.
Eso era el error en tu HTML y js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US"> 
 <head> 
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
  <title>Titulo de la pagina</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
 
 </head>
 <body BGCOLOR="#000000" DIR="LTR">
  
  <div id="container"> 
   
   <header>
    <h1 ALIGN=CENTER><font color="#ff0000">Header</font></h1> 
   </header> 
   
   <center>
    <a href="lab.html">
     <img src="inicio.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='inicio.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='inicio.jpg'"/>  
    </a> 
   </center>
   
   <hr color="#0080FF"> 
   
   <h2><font color="#ff0000">¿Qué es?</font></h2> 
   
   <p><font color="#2E7429">texto1</font></p> 
   
   <p><font color="#2E7429">texto2</font></p> 
   
   <h2><font color="FEFEFE"></font></h2> 
   
   <h2><font color="#ff0000">header2</font></h2> 
   
   <p><font color="#2E7429">texto3</font></p> 
   
   <h2><font color="#ff0000">header3</font></h2> 
   
   <p><font color="#2E7429">texto4</font></p> 
   
   <h2><font color="#2E7429">header4)</font></h2> 
   
   <br><br> 
   
   <font size="6" color="#ff0000">  

    <p><marquee>texto5</marquee></p>  

   </font>  

   </div> 
  
   <script src="screen.js"></script> 
  
 </body> 

</html>
```

Como se nota, realicé varias modificaciones importantes. Pero aún queda cosas que solucionar con respecto a la estetica: las declaraciones de estilos se pueden poner en la hojas de estilos style.css que tienes.
Y tiene mucha etiqueta font que son innecesarios; ya con una clase para todos estaría perfecto. Pero lo dejé así.

Comment: Gracias, mil gracias :)